# Access to UI thread for callbacks from Java library?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement an Android app as cleanly as possible.

To this end, I have defined a Java library for doing my logic and non-Android specific functionality.

For example, my app does a lot of network calls to REST apis and generates models and validation.

The library is using Retrofit and it handles asynchronous calls. However, now I need to chain calls and this means either:

1. Callback from first call triggers next request (potentially leading to 'callback hell').
2. Entering on the UI thread by default, create a new thread to do the requests, but then I need to be able to join the UI thread again when returning to the caller.

I'm not keen on (1) as we already have code like this and its a mess.

(2) would be my preferred option if there was a way to get a reference to the incoming thread (UI thread), then be able to join it again when the models are ready to be returned.

Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "chain calls" and what has this to do with the ui thread? can you give us example code?

Comment: after one request, make another. By default, Retrofit will provide callbacks that run on the original request.

Comment: I use option 2 with an asynctask.

Comment: You can also try option 3, using RxJava and chain `Observables`.

Comment: I"m looking at RxJava now. Not the easiest thing to understand but it seems to fit with my use case!

Comment: is there a way to use RxJava thats says the result should go back to a specific thread? That way, I can reference the current thread (UI thread), tell RxJava to run the retrofit call in a seperate thread, and then notify the original (UI) thread.

Comment: As described on the Retrofit [website](http://square.github.io/retrofit/): "Observable requests are subscribed asynchronously and observed on the same thread that executed the HTTP request. To observe on a different thread (e.g. Android's main thread) call `observeOn(Scheduler)` on the returned `Observable`."

Comment: actually what Retrofit does is: calls the api on the background thread and runs your callback in your Main thread (or any thread which you call the api from). there isnt any problem with calling an api in other api callback. if your problem is just a clean code and you can use methods to do that and another option is RxJava.

Answer (score 2):

To run anything on a thread you need some kind of a message loop. The UI thread is a part of Android and I guess it's impossible to run something on it without access to Android classes.

It's easy to get the UI thread using system API. Then you can post runnables to be run on that thread.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // your code
    }
});
```

Comment: sure, but I'm in a pure Java library and I don't want to burden the callers with having to get off the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `AsyncTask` to accomplish this. An `AsyncTask` is, as the name suggests, an asynchronous class that has both a `doInBackground` method, which executes in the background similar to a `Thread`, and a `onPostExecute` method, which runs on the UI and allows you to perform any UI-related activities. More information on `AsyncTask` may be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: AsyncTask: "This class was deprecated in API level 30"